# How to use a logical disk partition as an SD card in Android-x86

Tags: sd-card, android-x86

Android-x86 4.0.4 (ICS) runs beautifully on my netbook and it can even mount USB sticks as SD cards, but now I would like to use an available hard disk space (logical partition, `/dev/sda7`) as a permanent SD card.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.x86/3531), this is possible and it is as easy as adding the following line to `/etc/vold.fstab`:

```
dev_mount sdcard /mnt/sdcard auto SDCARD=/dev/sda7
```

But I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks. This is the first clue that this may be possible. But I just tried this and it didn't work for me. There is a mention there that another step is necessary: Changing `MAX_PARTITIONS` from 4 to **8** in `DirectVolume.h` but my system has no trace of a file named `DirectVolume.h`.

Comment: FYI: As soon as I tried this, the touch pad stopped working... Turns out switching back from Android's shell (`Alt+F7`) is very close to disabling the touchpad on this netbook (`Fn+F7`). No cause for alarm.